# can't Call Other Service in Select Method- Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query to get all Orders with detail . I have a query like this :

```
 return
           _orderMasters.OrderByDescending(row => row.Code).Where(row => row.Code == code).Include(row => row.Orderdetails)
             .Select(row => new OrderViewModel
             {
                 Code = row.Code,
                 // other fields
                 Items = row.Orderdetails.Select(detail => new OrderItemViewModel
                 {
                     ProductcombinationId = detail.ProductCombinationId,
                     ProductId=detail.ProductAttributeCombination.ProductId,
                     ProductName = detail.ProductCombination.Product.Name,
                     ProductCombinationName=_productCombinationService.GetCombinationsName(detail.ProductCombinationId,detail.ProductCombination.ProductId) // * this row
                 }).ToList(),
                 ShippingAddress = new AddressViewModel()
                 {
                     //set fileds value
                 }
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

In line that `*` I need get ProductcombinationName , to do this I call Method in another Service , but getting this Error :

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
```

First Idea Is , add `foreach` for All rows and call that Method to get ProductcombinationName , But I don't know is it a good way ?

Answer (score 1):

you can not use c# functions into linq because linq try to execute code on sql side where sql doesn't understand what your c# function is and give error.
for this, 
you can do like

```
                 Items = row.Orderdetails.Select(detail => new OrderItemViewModel
                 {
                     ProductcombinationId = detail.ProductCombinationId,
                     ProductId=detail.ProductAttributeCombination.ProductId,
                     ProductName = detail.ProductCombination.Product.Name,
                     ProductCombination = detail.ProductCombination // need to add for next operation
                 }).ToList(),
```

and then

```
foreach(var item in Items)
{
     // add ProductCombinationName code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework will not run C# code as part of its query, it has to be able to convert the query to an actual `SQL` expression.

So we will have to restructure your query expression into an expression that Entity Framework can handle.

```
var orders = _orderMasters.OrderByDescending(row => row.Code)
                          .Where(row => row.Code == code)
                          .Include(row => row.Orderdetails)
                          .ToList();


return   orders.Select(row => new OrderViewModel
         {
             Code = row.Code,
             // other fields
             Items = row.Orderdetails.Select(detail => new OrderItemViewModel
             {
                 ProductcombinationId = detail.ProductCombinationId,
                 ProductId=detail.ProductAttributeCombination.ProductId,
                 ProductName = detail.ProductCombination.Product.Name,
                 ProductCombinationName=_productCombinationService.GetCombinationsName(detail.ProductCombinationId,detail.ProductCombination.ProductId) // * this row
             }).ToList(),
             ShippingAddress = new AddressViewModel()
             {
                 //set fileds value
             }
         }).FirstOrDefault();
```